# Python webdriver in IE returns None for all find_elements

Tags: python, internet-explorer, testing, selenium

I am developing tests using the latest version of Selenium 2 in python, installed with `pip install -U selenium`. I have a series of tests that run correctly using `webdriver.Firefox()`, but do not with `webdriver.Ie()`. It opens and navigates to the page correctly, but any attempt to access elements in that page fails. It does not appear to be a problem in other pages, but I cannot identify what would be causing the problem with mine.

I can generate the problem easily by building an instance of the webdriver with:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Ie()
browser.get("page url")
browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("html") #returns None!
```

I'm looking for any clues as to why this might be.

Comment: i am not even able to do it with Firefox driver even.

Answer (score 0):

If you are exactly using this code, there are absolutely some problems.

First, I think it's better to assign return value of find to a variable and then check its value; I mean `html_tags = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("html")`.

After that, I thin you should use `browser.find_element_by_tag_name("html")`; because every page has just one tag with name "html". Your code is true if you want to achieve all tag elements with name "html".

Finally I think you want to access page source; in that case, you should use one of these:

1. `html_text = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("html").text`
2. `html_text = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("html")[0].text`

Just to cover all the states, could you please tell me what is the URL that you are trying to access; because I tried multiple webpages with your code (exactly yours, not after my own edits) and everything was fine.